# Puzzle from Pythagoras

Tags: word, knowledge, cipher

**Pythagoras wants to…**

```
If 1a,2b,20k,50v and 600x

Then what is 100 10 1000 3 ?
```

My original puzzle

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> When I googled ‘Greek numbers’ because of the Pythagoras hint I found:

> [image]

> The numbers in the top half of the puzzle seem to be next to their Greek Letter counterpart.

> So converting the numbers in the bottom half into Greek letters you get.

> **PLAY**

Comment: Yes this is correct good job!

Comment: Can’t believe this was unanswered for 5 hours.

Comment: @PDT Perhaps the others who went as far thought "eub nycun vbgn tnzzn? euvnt? anu, gung pna'g or vg"

Comment: I can’t believe I didn’t see it right away, as I was recently dealing with Greek numbers…

Comment: @PierrePaquette I can’t remember how many times I have felt something similar after finding out the solution to a puzzle lol.